# How can I restore the "Favorites" section of explorer after all entries have been deleted?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer

The image below illustrates the section:
[image]

Comment: See if my answer [here](http://superuser.com/a/544645/138343) helps.

Comment: Your answer there did not help. I could not get the favorites to re-appear after trying both options.

Comment: So you copied the Links folder from another profile and recreated Desktop.ini ***and*** tried the **Restore favorite links** option afterwards and still no change? Are you sure you didn't do anything else besides deleting the Links folder?

Comment: That did in fact fix the issue - after restart.

Answer (score 0):

Make a right click on the favorit Icon and select "restore favorite links"

[image]

**(Image-) Source:**

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/104440-favorites-restore-default-favorite-links-navigation-pane.html

Comment: This didn't restore the links for me.

Comment: have you moved the userprofile or delete the folder C:\Users\<USERNAME>\Links?

Comment: Yes I deleted \Links

Comment: Restoring the \Links folder put three shortcuts back *inside* the favorites folder, but on the side bar, there still are no links.

Comment: create the desktop.ini /this is mine in the folder): 
`[.ShellClassInfo]
        LocalizedResourceName=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-21810
        IconResource=%SystemRoot%\system32\imageres.dll,-185
        DefaultDropEffect=4
        [LocalizedFileNames]
        RecentPlaces.lnk=@shell32.dll,-37217
        Desktop.lnk=@shell32.dll,-21769
        Downloads.lnk=@shell32.dll,-21798`

And try the command to restore again.